# Does it cost anything to build an application on Symbian phone of Nokia?

Tags: symbian, arm, nokia

IDE, build tools, emulator... things that i must pay for them without any choice to replace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Carbide C++](http://www.forum.nokia.com/Library/Tools_and_downloads/Other/Carbide.c++/) IDE and [Qt SDK](http://developer.nokia.com/Develop/Qt/Tools/) and [Symbian SDKs](http://www.forum.nokia.com/Library/Tools_and_downloads/Other/Symbian_SDKs/), all of which are free.

http://developer.symbian.org/wiki/index.php/Category:Symbian_Signed :

> In terms of cost if you plan to deploy
>   your application commercially you will
>   need a Publisher ID which costs $200
>   per year and each time you sign a SIS
>   file it will cost €10 using Express
>   Signed and €150 if you use Certified
>   Signed.

https://publish.ovi.com/info/ :

Ovi Store will sell your app, giving you 70% of the revenue. Registering as a publisher on Ovi Store will cost 50 €.

So, besically, you can get development tools for free, but distributing your app will cost if it is a commercial application.

Comment: Nokia recently announced a further reduction of the cost of deploying commercial application on the Ovi store.

Answer (score 1):

These are all free. You have to pay for signing your application at the end for distributing